# Order of List<Ref<Obj>> field not persisted

Tags: objectify

I have a field in my Entity with a One-to-Many relationship like so:

private List> entityB = new ArrayList>();

Let's say I have added entityB1 and entityB2 to the list.  I can persist and retrieve the data and everything is fine.

However, let's say I later reorder the list, so it's entityB2 then entityB1. I persist the object again, but when I retrieve the object back, it turned back into the original order.

How do I ensure the order of the list is persisted?

Comment: It should come back in the order last saved. With the exception of Text and Blob types (GAE behavior), List contents are not reordered. You'll need to post more code to find out exactly what is going on - possibly you are querying for the object and seeing its eventually consistent (stale) state.

Comment: EntityB is embedded, right ?

Comment: @stickfigure -- you are right -- what I was doing is making the change, then shutdown and restart the dev environment -- if I waited longer before shutting down, the problem doesn't occur.  It seems like it hasn't been committed yet.  Thanks! I can't mark your comment as an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should come back in the order last saved. With the exception of Text and Blob types (GAE behavior), List contents are not reordered. You'll need to post more code to find out exactly what is going on - possibly you are querying for the object and seeing its eventually consistent (stale) state.